# How to disable CakePHP Form Combo?

Tags: php, cakephp, combobox, formhelper

I'm trying to disable this CakePHP combo:

`echo $this->Form->input('backupid', array('options' => $users_backup, 'class'=>'autocompletar', 'empty' => true, "label"=>__('Backup'), 'id' => 'cmbBackup'));`

When I click this Checkbox:

`echo $this->Form->input('criticalresource');`

I've tried to add the property 'disabled' and 'readonly' in every combo element

[The following image contains part of my DOM where you can see the Checkbox and the Combobox :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iByTd.jpg)

¿Is there any way to DISABLE that combo? I'd rather prefer a JS procedure, but every answer is welcome!

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find an alternative answer: I'll put a 'div' above and insert this class inside:

```
.disabledbutton {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your critical resource input with the following code

`echo $this->Form->input('criticalresource',array('onclick'=>'disableCombo();'));`

And in JavaScript

```
<script>
function disableCombo()
{
    var cmbBackup = document.getElementById("cmbBackup");
    cmbBackup.attr('disabled','disabled');
}
</script>
```